# TVD (total variable diminishing) and TVB methods for solving initial value problems

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

I trying to find out what TVD (total variable diminishing) and TVB methods are and I want to compare them with runge kutta method. the stuff I have already found are seem complex for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned TVD and TVB methods for scalar conservation laws from [Hyperbolic systems of conservation laws](https://books.google.es/books/about/Hyperbolic_systems_of_conservation_laws.html?id=hzvvAAAAMAAJ), by E. Godlewski and P-A. Raviart. It is quite an old book already, but it explains quite nicely how these type of methods arise.

Another book I used to read was [Numerical Methods for Conservation Laws](https://books.google.es/books?id=UvmpBwAAQBAJ&dq=Numerical+Methods+for+Conservation+Laws) by R. J. LeVeque. I think there ares several editions of this book; you can find an old (but enough) edition [here](http://www.fenomec.unam.mx/ramon/docs/LeVeque.pdf).

Unfortunatelly, I do not remember if there is anything about Runge-Kutta methods.